# Why does this code with free monad interpreter compile?

Tags: scala, free-monad

I'm trying to understand free monads. So with help of tutorials I wrote toy example to play with and now I don't understand why does it compile. Here it is:

```
import cats.free.Free
import cats.instances.all._
import cats.~>

trait Operation[+A]

case class Print(s: String) extends Operation[Unit]

case class Read() extends Operation[String]


object Console {

  def print(s: String): Free[Operation, Unit] = Free.liftF(Print(s))

  def read: Free[Operation, String] = Free.liftF(Read())

}

object Interpreter extends (Operation ~> Option) {
  // why does this compile?
  override def apply[A](fa: Operation[A]): Option[A] = fa match {
    case Print(s) => Some(println(s))
    case Read() => Some(readLine())
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val program = for {
      _ <- Console.print("What is your name?")
      name <- Console.read
      _ <- Console.print(s"Nice to meet you $name")
    } yield ()
    program.foldMap(Interpreter)
  }
}
```

I'm talking about apply method of Interpreter. It should return Option[A], but I can return Option[Unit] and Option[String] here so I assume it should be a compilation error. But it's not. This code compiles and works(although Idea tells me that it's an error). Why is that?

UPD: but why doesn't this compile?

```
def test[A](o: Operation[A]): Option[A] = o match {
    case Print(s) => Some(s)
    case Read() => Some(Unit)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `apply` method is supposed to return `Option[A]` where `A` is determined by the type of the argument. That is if the argument has type `Operation[Unit]`, the result should also be an `Option[Unit]` and so on.

Now your body adheres to that contract perfectly. Yes, you do have a case where you return an `Option[Unit]` instead of a general `Option[A]`, but you only do that if the argument was an instance of `Print` and thus an `Operation[Unit]`. That is you only ever return an `Option[Unit]` when the argument was an `Operation[Unit]`, so the contract is not broken. The same is true with `Read` and `String`. Note that if you returned an `Option[Unit]` in the case for `Read`, that'd be an error because you'd now be returning a type other than that of the argument.

So that's why the code is semantically correct, but why does it compile? That's because the Scala type checker (unlike IntelliJ's approximation thereof) is smart enough to take the additional type information into account when pattern matching. That is, in the `case Print` it knows that you've just matched a value of type `Operation[A]` against a pattern of type `Operation[Unit]`, so it assigns `A = Unit` inside the case's body.

---

Regarding your update:

```
case Print(s) => Some(s)
```

Here we have a pattern of type `Operation[Unit]` (remember that `Print` extends `Operation[Unit]`), so we should get a result of type `Option[Unit]`, but `Some(s)` has type `Option[String]`. So that's a type mismatch.

```
case Read() => Some(Unit)
```

First of all `Unit` it the companion object of the `Unit` type, so it has its own type, not type `Unit`. The only value of type `Unit` is `()`.

Aside from that, it's the same situation as above: The pattern has type `Operation[String]`, so the result should be `Operation[String]`, not `Operation[Unit]` (or `Operation[Unit.type]`).

Comment: Wow, scalac is really smart. Thank you.

Comment: I've already accepted the answer, but can you look at my update?

Comment: My bad, sorry. It works as you've sad. I removed update.

Comment: Since you've already answered on my update I write it back:) Sorry again and thank you for clear answer.